# Spring Boot - spring.jpa.hibernate - how to call with sudo?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a project for my work and the way they setup the mysql server to be able to connect I need to do

sudo myqsl -p

When I try to launch my spring boot app, it fails to connect to the mysql server..
How can I tell jpa hibernate to call the mysql with sudo rights? Is it even possible ?

I have tried launching the spring boot jar with sudo and it doesn't carry on to the mysql connection somehow

My application.properties contain those credentials

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mood
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

The database mood exists on the server and the user also exist. I can connect via ssh without any issues, using sudo.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The command-line `mysql` is using a Unix socket to connect and authenticate. You need to add a database user (and put that user's credentials in your application properties).

Comment: Hi Chrylis, I do have a setting for the user and password and it is working when I manually connect on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to connect to mysql in JPA with sudo rights, but you should be able to connect using the JDBC Connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:portnumber:username:password
```

As a test, why don't you code a little class that will connect to the database, perform a simple SELECT statement and bring back a result set.

You shouldn't have to connect to the mysql client with sudo, but I infer that when you say "they setup" you mean the system admins. Ask them nicely to set up the mysql client as a normal command.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you @jorge_rs. I will try this and come back to report here!

Comment: Well turns out that they changed it :) great success